# How to delete a list of users from Tableau server (both with content and without content) at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, tableau-api

I am building an automatization script to delete users from Tableau server. Before you delete the user you have to check that the user owns any content or not. If it has content then the script has to change the ownership then delete the user.
If it has nothing then the script deletes the user easily.
And I use a csv file to iterate through all of the users being removed so it has to deal with multiple user at the same time (both users with content and without content).

My problem is that the script cannot remove users with content and without content at the same time, only works with one type.
If the user has no content in Tableau then the script easily remove that user, but if in the csv file has a user with content then that user deletion will fail.

How can I optimize my script to change the ownership if there is any content and remove all users at the same time?

This is only the main part of the code but I build this base on this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-remove-tableau-server-users-who-own-content-bb84fbd6948d

Am I doing in a right way?
(I am a beginner and this is my first script, so please don't laugh if I do something really stupid. :))

```
def main():
    try:
        remove_user(conn, users_df, owner_id=user_id_to_remove)
    except:
        for inx, row in enumerate(owner_swap_df.itertuples()):
            response = change_content_owner(conn, row.content_type, row.id, new_owner_id)
            print(response.json())
        remove_user(conn, users_df, owner_id=user_id_to_remove)
    finally:
        conn.sign_out()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you add the error message you get when trying to delete a user that still has content? And have you validated that your `change_content_owner()` is actually changing ownership?